# DrawRect Square/Rectangle user values

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drawrect

I've got the books, I've checked the apple docs and something is not clicking.

Here's what I want to do: get user values and draw a square/rectangle with them.

A window with one custom view on the right.

On the left two text fields, two labels (width and height) and a button "Draw".
On the right DrawView.

There's how one could do it:

You have to do the connection for the textFields and the button in your appDelegate and also have an IBOutlet for your customView.

In your customView you need to have the two variables which will hold the values from the textField. Don't use property/synthesize because once you set the values you need to call setNeedsDisplay in your customView-DrawView.

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#import "DrawView.h"

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (assign) IBOutlet NSWindow *window;

@property (weak) IBOutlet DrawView *myDrawView;


@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *widthTextField;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *heightTextField;

- (IBAction)draw:(id)sender;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "DrawView.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

- (IBAction)draw:(id)sender {

    [_myDrawView setWidth:[_widthTextField floatValue]];
    [_myDrawView setHeight:[_heightTextField floatValue]];
}
```

DrawView.h

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface DrawView : NSView {

    float width;
    float height;
}

-(void) setWidth: (float) aWidth;
-(void) setHeight: (float) aHeight;

@end
```

DrawView.m

```
#import "DrawView.h"

@implementation DrawView

#pragma mark - Setters

-(void) setWidht:(float)aWidth {

    width = aWidth;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

-(void) setHeight:(float)aHeight {
    height = aHeight;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}


#pragma mark - Drawing

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {

        [self setWidth:10];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {

    //BackGround Color
    [[NSColor whiteColor] setFill];
    NSRectFill(dirtyRect);
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];


    NSBezierPath* square = [NSBezierPath bezierPath];
    [square setLineWidth:2];

    NSRect squareRect = NSMakeRect(10,10,width,height);

    [square appendBezierPathWithRoundedRect:squareRect xRadius:5 yRadius:5];

    [square stroke];
}
@end
```

That's it. I don't know if there's a better way to do it. It seems a bit bizarre.

Comment: Are you sure you're IBOutlet's are linked to the NSTextField objects in your XIB? Check for nil of `self.widthTextField` before calling `floatValue`.

Comment: Yes. If in my Draw method i do: { NSLog(@"width %f ", [self.widthTextField floatValue]; and [self setNeedsDisplay:YES]; }     and i put the same NSLog in the drawRect. When i run it i get in the console 0 -- which is ok because is the first run of drawRect. But after i click the Draw button i get ,let's say width 20, and width 0.0. The first one is from Draw and the second is from drawRect. So yes the values are 0 in drawRect, why?

Comment: check if `self.widthTextField` is nil, if it is, you haven't connected the outlet in interface builder.

Comment: I see `[square stroke]`, but I don't see where you set the stroke color (e.g. `[[NSColor blackColor] setStroke]`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it´s nill in drawRect but just before it reaches drawRect it's not because I can calculate the area with the same values...Could you please try it. It takes only 5' to do it.

Comment: Ok, so i found the answer: You basically need to have a pointer to your custom view in your appDelegate and you need to make your own setters in the customView class. Maybe it's not the most elegant way to do it but it works. I'll update the code.